# if(x==y==z) works, if(x!=y!=z) does not

Tags: c++, c

Why is:

```
if(x!=y!=z)
```

handled as:

```
x=1
y=1
z=2
```

??

I just noticed it today.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking for. Can you check that you have added every detail required to understanding your question?

Comment: Devs who code like make collaborative work environments suck.

Comment: Both work. Neither does what you imagine. A good book on basic C (section "operators") will help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`x != y` and `x == y` return booleans.
You're comparing `z` to those booleans.

Neither of them will work they way you want them to.

Comment: This is not correct. `==` and `!=` bind left to right. `x` is being compared to `y` in both examples.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I wasn't sure about that; fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It probably is parsed as `if ((x!=y) !=z)` which does not do what you think `if (x!=y!=z)` should do (but does not).

Likewise `if (x==y==z)` probably means `if ((x==y)==z)` to the compiler which is not what you want.

Enable the warnings given by your compiler. With GCC, that means `gcc -Wall` and it would tell you `warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '=='`

Recall that a boolean expression like `x==y` gives a zero (when false) or non-zero (when true) result. Writing `((x==y) + (z==t))` is very poor taste, but makes sense for the compiler.

Comment: Why do you say "probably"? I can't think of a case where it isn't definitely.

Comment: I was saying probably, because without the standard at hand, I was not entirely sure it is not parsed as `(x!=(y!=z))` which would have been very counter-intuitive (even to me).

Comment: The last line is correct for C, but not for C++ (where boolean expressions evaluate to `false`)

Answer (score 3):

`x == y == z` is equivalent to `(x == y) == z`.  In this case, `(1 == 1) == 2`, or `true == 2`, which is `false` because `true == 1`, not 2.

`x != y != z` is equivalent to `(x != y) != z`.  In this case, `(1 != 1) != 2`, or `false != 2`, which is `true` because `false == 0`, not 2.

C(++) relational operators aren't chained like in Python.  If you want to check whether three numbers are all equal to each other, use `(x == y) && (y == z)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `true == !0`, so both 1 and 2 would be true.

Comment: dan04 has it right. `(1==1)` is of type `bool` and has value `true`. While both `bool` and `int` are integral types, they are not of the same type. Per the promotion rules, the `bool` value needs to promoted to an `int` so it can be compared to 2. In that conversion the `bool` value `true` is converted to 1, and `1==2` is false.

Comment: @TMN `!0` doesn't evaulate to both `1` and `2` simultaneously.  Since `!` is a boolean operator, `0` gets implicitly converted to `false`, so `!0` becomes `true`, which is then implicitly converted to `1` if you try to compare it with an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(x==y==z)
```

will not work untill the value u will use for z be 1 or 0 but u can take the value of x and y anything
As when u try with the value 1 or 0 then the if will take its parameters as

```
 if((x==y)==z)
```

this is happening because it first evaluate whatever the value in x and y and the answer will be in boolean and then it checks with z which it expects to be boolean. so if (x==y) be and z is 1(true) then code will be executed else it wont.Same thing will happen with (x!=y!=z). try with z=1 or 0 and x,y be anything.